# Can I commit a video with GitHub API?

Tags: github, commit, github-api, post-commit

I need to upload the video (.mp4) with GitHub API. I fount a way to upload a text file. Something like this:

POST /repos/:user/:repo/git/trees

```
{
  "base_tree": "{{sha-base-tree}}",
  "tree": [
    {
      "path": "NewFile1.txt",
      "mode": "100644",
      "type": "blob",
      "content": "This is NewFile1."
    }
  ]
}
```

In the 'content' section need to paste a text of the text file. But what if I have an .mp4 file? How to upload it? I can't to find any info about it on Google. Thanks.